# How to get notification if any data is entered into excel sheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to make an application using c# to get the notification if any changes made in the excel sheet. Suppose Someone has added some data or modified some data then at that time i should get the window notification that some changes has been made.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the context of a web app?  If not, please remove the `asp.net` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to know when they actually *save* the file, you can use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class to monitor the directory.  You can do whatever you want once a change to the file is made.